# Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation. Make sure Kotlin compilation is running on a JDK, not JRE. Any Solution of this

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin

I am very new in react Native i tried every solution to solve this error but not succeeded i update the path ,install java 8 or trying other solution as well but it still not running my app.Please help me out in this.
I Got this Error...

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.

> Failed to query the value of task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin' property 'compilerRunner$kotlin_gradle_plugin'.
> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation. Make sure Kotlin compilation is running on a JDK, not JRE.

I tried to update my env variables as well i install java 8 but still not solved my problem

Comment: What does `java -version` say?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_351"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_351-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.351-b10, mixed mode)

Comment: So you have installed a Java 8 JRE (Java Runtime Environment) not a JDK (Java Development Kit).  That means that there is no Java compiler and Gradle needs a Java compiler.  Uninstall the Java 8 JRE, then download and install a Java 8 JDK instead.  (It sounds like you reinstalled the JRE. That doesn't help.)